# Codecs UDT's in Cassandra

Tags: scala, cassandra, datastax, datastax-java-driver

I have a table in Cassandra with Map

I have define MyUDT as a case class in Scala and trying to read it. When I save it to Cassandra, it works, but later, I want to read it with the driver and I have some problems.

I'm trying to do this:

```
 val result = session.execute(s"select ls_my_udt from ks.myTable  WHERE id = 0")
 val queryConContrato = result.one().getMap[String, MyUDT]("ls_my_udt ", classOf[String], classOf[MyUDT])
```

When  I execute this query I get an error:

```
com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.CodecNotFoundException: Codec not found for requested operation: [frozen<ks.myudt> <-> com.MyUDT]

    at com.datastax.driver.core.CodecRegistry.notFound(CodecRegistry.java:679)
```

My TYPE is:

```
CREATE TYPE MyUDT (
id text,
field text
);
```

My case class is:

This is the error if I don't annote the case class

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: @UDT annotation was not found on class com.MyUDT
```

And my case class

```
@UDT(keyspace="ks", name="myUDT")
case class ProductUDT(id: String,
                      field: String )
```